# When doing finding missing sides in trigonometry do I have to divde or multiply?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

so I have a test in like an hour and I'm confused.

Let's suppose that the hypotenuse is $8$ $\mathrm{cm}$ and our angle is $40^\circ$ and the opposite side is missing.

So $\sin B = \frac{b}{8\textrm{ cm}}$ is $5$ $\mathrm{cm}$ when I multiply.

But when I divide on my calculator I get this $12$ $\mathrm{cm}$.

I was told I had to multiply but $b$ is bigger than the hypotenuse...

Comment: Your equation $\sin40 = \frac{b}{8}$ is correct. So multiply both sides by 8. $b = \sin(40)\times 8 = 5.142cm$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $\sin40^\circ = \frac{b}{8}$ is correct.

So multiply both sides by 8.

$b = \sin(40^\circ)\times 8 = 5.142cm$

EDIT:

Suppose the opposite side was given as 8, and you're told to find the hypoteneuse. That's a different problem. In that case

$\sin(40^\circ) = \frac{8}{h}$

Then multiply both sides by h, and divide both sides by $\sin(40^\circ)$ to get

$h = \frac{8}{\sin(40^\circ)} = 12.45cm$